# check if "change" event is from keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onchange

I have `on` `change` trigger that gets the event :

```
  $(document).on('change', '.class', function (eve) {
```

How can I know if the change is from the mouse or from the keyboard by the event variable?

Comment: use `mousekeyup , mousekeydown` ,`keyup,keydown`.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Comment: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2369-mouse-vs-keyboard---determining-click-initiator-using-a-jquery-custom-event.htm

Comment: May I know the reason it matters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure the event is coming from the keyboard, use `keydown`. To make sure it comes from the mouse, use `mousekeydown`. So you would need to register 2 different events, for each device:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.class', function (e) {
   // From keyboard
}
$(document).on('mousekeydown', '.class', function (e) {
   // From mouse
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible because a `change` event may only fire when the concerned element loses focus, after several changes were made with several different input methods, including mouse and keyboard.

Test it with this `input` element: enter some text with keyboard, paste some text using the context menu (right click), and maybe move some characters by dragging them with the mouse into a different position. Then press the button. Only now you get the `change` event:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.class', function (eve) {
    console.log('change event occurred');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="class">
<button>Button</button>
```